# How to make Excel add-in debugger launch with specific file?

Tags: .net, debugging, excel, vsto

I have Excel add-in project, and I need to make it open specific Excel file when I run debug. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested it but adding the following code to Startup event should do it:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    #if DEBUG
        this.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\file.xlsx");
    #endif
}
```